# Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Server in soa12c

Tags: oracle, soa, osb, soa-suite

I have installed the oracle soa 12c in windows.I am getting the 
Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Server
Stopping Derby server...

**Please find the below log.**

The system cannot find the path specified.

---

** Setting up SOA specific environment for win...

---

PATH=C:\ORACLE_FMW\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\badri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\thirdparty\edifecs\XEngine\bin
.
JAVA_OPTIONS=
.

---

** End SOA Specific environment setup  for win.

---

.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms768m -Xmx1536m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\bam\lib\bam-timerlistener.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\user-patch.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\soa-startup.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\features\com.oracle.db.jdbc7-dms.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\odsi_xquery2004_12.1.3\odsi.xquery.modules_12.1.3.0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.common.adapters_11.1.1\oracle.soa.common.adapters.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.cloud.adapter_12.1.3\oracle.cloud.adapter.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb\lib\servicebus-common.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\communications\modules\config-12.1.3.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\communications\modules\userprefs-config-12.1.3.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.xdk_12.1.3\xsu12.jar;\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules.xquery_10.3.1.0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\db2jcc4.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1\config\soa-infra;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\fabric-url-handler_11.1.1.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\quartz-all-1.6.5.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.fabric_11.1.1\oracle.soa.fabric.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.fabric_11.1.1\fabric-runtime-ext-wls.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.adapter_11.1.1\oracle.soa.adapter.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.b2b_11.1.1\oracle.soa.b2b.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\internal\features\jrf_wlsFmw_oracle.jrf.wls.classpath_12.1.3.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.fabric_11.1.1\tracking-api.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\commons-cli-1.1.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.mgmt_11.1.1\soa-infra-mgmt.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb\lib\version.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb\lib\servicebus.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1\config\osb;C:\ORACLE~1\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\com.oracle.cie.config-wls-online_8.1.0.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=C:\ORACLE_FMW\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\badri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa\thirdparty\edifecs\XEngine\bin
.

---

- To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
- password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
- server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
- console at http:\hostname:port\console        *

  ---

starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_7\bin\java    -Xms768m -Xmx1536m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs="oracle.mds.net.protocol|oracle.fabric.common.classloaderurl.handler|oracle.fabric.common.uddiurl.handler|oracle.bpm.io.fs.protocol" -Dopss.version=12.1.3 -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1\config\fmwconfig\carml -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1\config\fmwconfig\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1\servers\AdminServer\tmp_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ossoiap_12.1.3,C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.oamprovider_12.1.3,C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_12.1.3 -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=true -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common -Djrf.version=12.1.3 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1 -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1\config\fmwconfig\servers\AdminServer -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1\config\fmwconfig -Doracle.mds.filestore.preferred= -Dadf.version=12.1.3 -Doracle.osb.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb  -da -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server  -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder  -da:org.apache.xmlbeans... -Dem.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\em -DINSTANCE_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain -Djava.awt.headless=true -Doracle.sysman.util.logging.mode=dual_mode -Dsoa.archives.dir=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa -Dsoa.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa -Dsoa.instance.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\BASE_D~1 -Dtangosol.coherence.log=jdk -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl -Dweblogic.transaction.blocking.commit=true -Dweblogic.transaction.blocking.rollback=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks -Doracle.xml.schema\Ignore_Duplicate_Components=true -Doracle.xdkjava.compatibility.version=11.1.1 -Doracle.soa.compatibility.version=11.1.1 -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Dbam.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa -Dums.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common   -Djava.util.logging.manager=oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ODLLogManager  **weblogic.Server
Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Server
Stopping Derby server...
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Derby server stopped.**

Comment: double check your JVM/JDK version. Also http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#SOAQS251  and  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23104_01/download_readme_1221/download_readme_1221.htm

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem on Weblogic 12.1.3. To resolve it try the following:

1. Find the *"startWebLogic.cmd"* script:

According to your log message, check  *"C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain"* folder, where 
*"C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home"* - installation directory,
*"base_domain"* - your domain name

2. Change the Weblogic starting script

After line `"set DOMAIN_HOME=..."` add a new variable called MW_HOME that specifies your installation directory:

```
...
set DOMAIN_HOME=...
set MW_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home
...
```

Save the file.

3. Run your server.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I changed the path of `WL_HOME` in `setDomainEnv.cmd`
Make sure that path points to server location. In my case it pointed to the server on access limited disc.

Copying server location to another location should help too but make sure `Env`. variables were changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to weblogic server is not getting required class files to get started.To resolve this follow the below steps.

1.Go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper

2.Now rename the system12.2.1.0.42.151022.0031 tosystem12.2.1.0.42.151022.0031.bak

3.Now create the domain again and configure it.Now you can start  the server.

Incase the above steps is not working for you.Try to create the compact server.For steps on how to create the compact server refer the below link

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/compactdomain.htm#SOAQS220

Answer (score 0):

Please check`set enableHotswapFlag=`on setDomainEnv.cmd. I got this error when I set it to true.

Answer (score -1):

It was happening, (for me) due to there being a space in my user name, as explained [here](http://oraclesoabpmsolution.blogspot.com/2016/09/oracle-jdeveloper-12c-error-not-find-or-load-main-class.html)